# Clean up function issue in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Made a cleanup function in my component's useEffect, but I'm still getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srsxJ.jpg) warning message?
Any ideas why?

My useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true

    if (mounted) readPost(`${C.API_ENDPOINT}/posts/${id}`)
    if (mounted && (status === 'success')) setSuccessMsg(true)

    window.addEventListener('click', () => {
        setSuccessMsg(false)
        resetStatus()
    })

    return () => {
        mounted = false

        window.removeEventListener('click', () => {
            setSuccessMsg(false)
            resetStatus()
        })
    }
}, [readPost, resetStatus, id, status])
```

Comment: Is the readPost performing a request or an asynchronous thing? If that's your case even though you're cleaning the evenListener the request is still running and that is why you get the warning.

Comment: readPost is performing a request to the server if mounted is true, but in the cleanup func I set it to false, so, if I'm getting it right, when the component is unmounted, readPost gets disabled.

Comment: Yes but you have to consider that it was set to true when the useEffect runs, even though you're setting the mounted to false, the request is still running, for example if you use the fetch api you need to pass an AbortController to cancel the request, or if you use axios you should use a cancel token, so when you unmount you are 100% sure that your request was cancelled.

Comment: I used AbortController and this really did the trick. Thank you for quick help.